# settext for more than one edittext in vertical lines

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, settext

I'm beginner in android development and i'm trying to build an app with multiple equations and i need the result to be viewed in one text and in vertical lines every result for equation viewed in line, i know how to show them together but it will show them either for the same line or in un-arranged manner like this code:

```
Result.setText("MDRD=" + Double.toString(m) + " MDRD.abbv" + Double.toString(b));
```

,, So what i have to do to show them like this????

MDRD= 9999 // any number

MDRD.abbv =8888 // any number

**,, in another way :**

if i have an equation and i want show the result in text, i'll use "Result.setText", also if i want to show more than one equation's result in the same text "Result", i can use "+", but what i want to show more than one equation's result in the same text "Result" but every equation's result appear in one line

Comment: Your description of what you want to achieve is unclear.

Comment: if i have an equation and want show it result in text, i'll use "Result.setText", also if i want to show more than one equation's result in the same text "Result", i can use "+", but what i want to show more than one equation's result in the same text "Result" but every equation's result appear in one line

Comment: Edit your questionto improve it, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right you are trying to add a line break to  textview (Result)?! This can be easily achieved by adding a newline `\n` to your String:

```
Result.setText("MDRD=" + Double.toString(m) + "\nMDRD.abbv" + Double.toString(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the newline character "\n", like this:

```
Result.setText("MDRD=" + Double.toString(m) + "\nMDRD.abbv" + Double.toString(b));
```